# Error 999999 with Project Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, error-999999

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1, and I'm working with monthly precipitation raster data from 1995 - 2015. Currently, I'm trying to get all of these raster layers (252 in total) to a different projection by using Project Raster (I'm using UTM NAD 1983 13N). I was doing a batch process (R click tool > Batch) with all of these layers.

All was going well, but while on the 210th raster layer, processing stopped at 78% and timed out with an `Error 999999: Error executing function.`(I mention the percentage because the time out occurs at the same value each time I've restarted the process.) The message I received simply stated that it "failed to copy raster dataset." In addition, it continues to give this error for all of the remaining rasters, and I cannot continue the process.

I've checked the rasters I'm projecting from, to see if I can diagnose some error with the original, and nothing is out of the ordinary; the other rasters that I was able to successfully project are all the same as the ones that spark the error (i.e. their extent, rows, columns, initial projection, cell size, etc. are all the same. The only difference is the pixel data they hold). The successfully processed rasters (1 to 209) also appear fine. Does anyone have any idea for why this is occurring?

Comment: Is it always the same actual raster that it fails on?

Comment: Perhaps review these Q&As: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Berror-999999%5D+project+raster+is%3Aquestion but 999999 errors are notoriously difficult to debug

Comment: @Midavalo Yes, although it does seem that each raster after the 210th one also has this error.

Comment: What happens if you do the first 209 and then start again from the 210th onwards?

Comment: @Midavalo The first 209 rasters projected without any issues. When I've retried the process again, I've been dealing with only 209 and onward. I've also taken groups of raster files out, just to see if there was a bad batch of sorts. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: What happens when you use the tool normally, not in batch, on just that 210th raster?

Comment: @PolyGeo sorry for the delay in reply. It still came up with an error. Although I still don't understand exactly what happened, I think there was an error (somehow) with a batch that I did previously, and when I corrected that, I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what happened, but I ended up going through all of my steps from the beginning (prior to me Project Rastering the layers - I had Raster Clipped these rasters previously). I focused on just the sections that started the error (210th raster and above), and that somehow fixed the problem. Even though they all appeared to be the same when I looked at those layers' properties, I'm thinking some sort of glitch happened during the earlier batch Raster Clip that I couldn't determine. I'm still looking into it, but I'll edit my answer if I find something new to add.